# DSolve fails with four variables

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

How is that DSolve has no trouble solving this:

```
DSolve[{
D[G[x1,x2,x3],x1]==0,
D[G[x1,x2,x3],x2]==0,
D[G[x1,x2,x3],x3]==0
},G[x1,x2,x3],{x1,x2,x3}]
```

but it fails to evaluate when there is a fourth variable:

```
DSolve[{
D[G[x1,x2,x3,x4],x1]==0,
D[G[x1,x2,x3,x4],x2]==0,
D[G[x1,x2,x3,x4],x3]==0,
D[G[x1,x2,x3,x4],x4]==0
},G[x1,x2,x3,x4],{x1,x2,x3,x4}]
```

I am using Mathematica 11.3.0.0.

Comment: Same problem with Version 12.0.  `DSolve[{D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x1] == 0, D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x2] == 0, D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x3] == 0}, G[x1, x2, x3, x4], {x1, x2, x3, x4}]` returns a solution.  So, the problem is with the number of equations, not of variables.  `DSolve` cannot be expected to solver every system of PDEs, but this seems rather elementary.  Also, `DSolve[{D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], x1] == 0, D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], x2] == 0, D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], x3] == 0, D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], x4] == 0}, G[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]` fails.   A bug, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

In V12.2, `DSolve` now handles the 4-variable case.

```
DSolve[{D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x1] == 0, D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x2] == 0, 
  D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x3] == 0, D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x4] == 0}, 
 G[x1, x2, x3, x4], {x1, x2, x3, x4}]

(*  {{G[x1, x2, x3, x4] -> C[1]}}  *)
```

It also handles a hundred, a thousand, or more:

```
nvars = 100;
vars = ToExpression@Array["x" <> ToString[#] &, nvars];
DSolve[Map[D[G @@ vars, #] == 0 &, vars], G @@ vars, vars]
```

For `nvars = 1000`, I raised `$RecursionLimit = 10000` and `$IterationLimit = 100000` and waited over 400 sec.